# setup and deployment visual basic 2010, ms-access database not found after installation

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010, setup-deployment

im using MS-access as my database. I've already finished the project and it is working perfectly fine.
my database location while  im still developing is in C:\Users\Users\documents and the other one located at C:\Users\Users\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\project1\project1\bin\debug

is bad to put the database at two different folder?

1st problem: now creating a setup and deployment project, i use setup wizard and checked all then build it. installation of setup is successful but when i try to run the program, it doesnt respond,

2nd problem: i cant see my 1st database located at program files, only the second one and maybe this is the cause of unresponsive app.

copying the debug files into other computer and copying manually my database to user\document which i have to change permission and the copied debug files runs well, but i have to create an installer. how to do it?

from my server explorer i was wondering there is only one database, yet my program works fine when running debug? reconnecting the unseen database would be a lot of work because it is my main database.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the database which is connected to your project and the path which is associated.

Try Application.StartUpPath in your connection.

Comment: i can't find application.startupPath but what i found is my database path value. 

I've tried to change the path of my 1st database to [datadirectory]\hs.accdb   same as my second one.  the project runs fine while debugging. but creating an installer doesnt include my 1st database.